# python test result reporting

Tags: python, unit-testing, reporting

My question is regarding python unittest reporting.
I am using the xmlrunner package which produces the xunit output which is used by Jenkins. In addition to that, I want to either produce an html output or print out the output in a nice custom format.
Note: I already know about HTMLTestRunner and it did not make me happy.
There are 3 problems:

- my tests are not displayed as suite groups (the report does not show the grouping)
- the test details are not shown (purpose of the test)
- the failure stack traces should not be shown in a report that is made for the management

**The question is how to iterate through the test results?**

Here is my test runner code:

```
import unittest
import os, sys
import xmlrunner

def getSuites(root):
    testSets = {"ts1":["tc1","tc2"], "ts2":["tc3","tc4"]}
    suites = unittest.TestSuite()
    for ts_name,ts in testSets.iteritems():
        ts_dir = "%s/%s" % (root, ts_name)
        sys.path.append(ts_dir)
        print "ts_dir = %s" % ts_dir
        for tc in ts:
            module = __import__(tc,{},{},['1'])
            suites.addTest(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(module))
    return suites

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    suites = getSuites(root)
    results = xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='test_reports').run(suites)
```

Note:

```
for r in results:
    print r
```

throws an exception saying that _XMLTestResult is not iterable.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in results.successes + results.failures + results.errors:
    print x
    #print x.get_description(), x.outcome
```

Comment: thanks, that made me a happy man. Is there a documentation for these? For instance, x.outcome = 0 means success, 1 means fail and 3 means skipped but what would be 2?

Comment: I read the source code. ( https://github.com/danielfm/unittest-xml-reporting/blob/master/src/xmlrunner/__init__.py )  There, you can find  "(SUCCESS, FAILURE, ERROR, SKIP) = range(4)".

Comment: successes, failures, errors, skipped are menthioned in http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult .